# Replace Index Number with New Customised Serial No

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing, str-replace

I want to replace the current index number of items of list with a new customised serial number

I have a list with different variables and they are indexed using below code

```
list_a = ["alpha","beta","romeo","nano","charlie"]

for idx, val in enumerate(list_a, start=1):

print("index number for %s is %d" % (val, idx))
```

This gives me following results.

```
index number for alpha is 1
index number for beta is 2
index number for romeo is 3
index number for nano is 4
index number for charlie is 5
```

Now I want to replace the above index numbers from 1 to 5 with a customized list as below

```
index number for alpha is 1Red
index number for beta is 2Blue
index number for romeo is 3Purple
index number for nano is 4Red
index number for charlie is 5Blue
```

Appreciate the help and many thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the rule of creating new serial number?

Comment: There is no rule, I have names that I want to replace with the serial number as mentioned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand you want replace the values of your `list_a` in a specific sequence and there is no logical/rule, Right?

So you can do it in lots of ways, but if do it you'll lose your date from the list_a, so I'll show you another two ways to solve this problem, ok?!

First way by **for**:

```
list_a = ["alpha","beta","romeo","nano","charlie"]
cust_list = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Purple', 'Red', 'Blue'] #create a new list

#Create your logical by for
for id_a, id_b, i in zip(list_a, cust_list, range(5)):
    cust_list[i] = str(i+1)+id_b

#Make some changes in your code and run it
for idx, val in enumerate(list_a, start=1):
    print("index number for %s is %s" % (val, cust_list[idx-1]))
```

Second way by **list comprehension** and **for**:

```
list_a = ["alpha","beta","romeo","nano","charlie"]
cust_list = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Purple', 'Red', 'Blue'] #create a new list

#adding new items by list comprehension
[cust_list.insert(i,str(i+1)+cust_list[i]) for i in range(len(list_a))]
#deleting old items
for i in range(5):
    del cust_list[-1]

#Make some changes in your code and run it
for idx, val in enumerate(list_a, start=1):
    print("index number for %s is %s" % (val, cust_list[idx-1]))
```

Your new data are storaged in `cust_list` you can check it out by `print(cust_list)`.

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked, I made a slight adjustment. Did not want the number so removed the bit "str(i+1)". Thanks alot for help

Comment: Just adding another layer....if for example the items in list_a are people and I want to send them email informing them about their new index number (assuming I have their emails)

Comment: For this case, if I were you I would use a `dictionary ` instead of a `list`, it's more easy to handle it.

Comment: Yes this is what I have done, I have created a dictionary of names vs email addresses, the challenge is how to integrate with above indexing function so the right email address can be fetched. Have tried different ways but not been able to link indexed result and pull out the email. Thanks

Comment: NameEmail = {
"Ale": "Ale@gmail.com",
"Dav": "Dav@gmail.com",
"Abe": "Abe@gmail.com",
"And": "And@gmail.com",
"Andr": "Andr@gmail.com"''
}

for i in NameEmail:
    print(NameEmail.get(i))

Comment: What i am missing in above is how to link the dictionary with my shuffled list so the email goes to right person. Just to summarise the whole process 1)- Shuffle name of people in a list. 2)- Assign them a new index number 3)Find email of that person from dictionary and send email (First two parts are done, just third part needs help). Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. My tip for you is use the function `zip` or two `for` statement, since the all email takes the user name, you can match the email by `if` statement, try this code:NameEmail = { "Ale": "Dav@gmail.com", "Dav": "Ale@gmail.com", "Abe": "Andr@gmail.com", "And": "And@gmail.com", "Andr": "Abe@gmail.com"}
keys = list(NameEmail.keys())
for i in keys:
    for j in list(NameEmail.values()):
        if i+'@' in j: print('{} matches {}'.format(i,j))

Comment: For security you can organize your code such as `NameEmail = [{'name': 'Ale', 'email': 'Ale@gmail.com'}, {'name': 'Dav', 'email': 'Dav@gmail.com'}, {'name': 'Andr', 'email': 'Andr@gmail.com'}]` or even `NameEmail = [('Ale', 'Ale@gmail.com'), ('Dav', 'Dav@gmail.com'), ('Andr', 'Andr@gmail.com')]` with tuple your data become immutable even if you shuffle the whole list,  so that's great.